# C# Listview Cant Edit it with Button

Tags: c#, forms, function, listview

I have a problem; I am trying to make a listview in C# Forms and then edit it with a button.

but it does not edit it. Could you help me out or give me a tip.

The listView is on `Form1` and with the second foreach loop I can see that its edited, but in the `Form1` `ListView` I dont see any changes. it is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
frm.InitializeComponent();
```

Comment: i get this error 
Opdracht_1.Form1.InitializeComponent()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: by using Form1 frm = new Form1(); you simply create a new instance of the Form1 form, are you actually displaying it?

Comment: what dos displaying it meens? 
look this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/vdPSf.jpg

Comment: oow it does work now but now it edit all the items in the foreach loop

Comment: Oke it works now i added a break, and edit the function tthanks for your help

Comment: Anima when i use the Show() now i have 2 Form1 if i use this.Close() in form1 the whole application Closes have a tip please?